# PHP json_Encode an array of json_encode-ed arrays

Tags: php, json

Im not sure what is happening, but if i do

```
json_encode()
```

On a single array, i get valid json, but if i do something like

```
$ar['key'] = "name";
$array[] = json_encode($ar);
$json = json_encode($array);
```

It will return invalid json like so:

```
["{"key":"name"}"]
```

The expected outcome is

```
[{"key":"name"}]
```

I have searched for hours trying to find what is going on.

Comment: [Is that really your code?](https://3v4l.org/2el73). I assume you meant `json_encode`, but there is more going on you aren't telling us.

Comment: json_encode is a function, not a variable so don't use the $ prefix to call it. And you are double-encoding your array. What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: `json_encode()` returns you a string.  You are then putting that *string* into an array and (re-)encoding it as JSON.

Comment: It would also help if we knew what you expected the outcome to be, it will help us figure out the proper way to reach it, because encoding an already encoded array will always return an escaped string version of whatever you supply for arguments.

Comment: FYI, that's not actually the output of that code.

Comment: Why are you calling `json_encode()` the first time if you didn't want to put a doubly-encoded object into the final result?

Comment: I typed this question while at school, sorry for the incorrect json_encode usage before, i did take this code directly from my PHP script, but changed the json and var names. I edited the original post to fix and explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of desired outcome, I can only assume you are trying to get a multidimensional array.

The correct way to achieve this would be to build an array of arrays, and then json_encode the parent array.

```
$data = array();
$data['fruits'] = array('apple','banana','cherry');
$data['animals'] = array('dog', 'elephant');
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Following this code, $json will have the following value

```
{"fruits":["apple","banana","cherry"],"animals":["dog","elephant"]}
```

It could then be parsed properly by javascript using `jQuery.parseJSON()`

Comment: You led me to the correct solution, along with my own thoughts through ought the day.  I needed to set an array of values and put them into another array, then json encode the final array

Answer (score 0):

Just json_encode the entire array.

```
$ar['key'] = "name";
$json = json_encode($ar);
```

json_encode returns a string, and json encoding a string will return a string.

Also it's json_encode, not $json_encode

Comment: I am doing this, but i need that to then be encoded with other json encoded items, to make a single json string